# How can I display a dialog canvas in Oracle Forms Builder?

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have built a form in which the user can view multiple rows of data pulled from a table. The user has the option to select a row, then pressing a button to reject the data in that row, (to be marked as rejected in some STATUS field).

I have also designed a rejection confirmation dialog with the ability for the user to enter some comments or reason for rejection.

I have set up the dialog canvas to appear on its own window with the Type proeperty set to Dialog.

When the user selects a row to reject, here is the code that gets executed:

```
BEGIN
  GO_BLOCK('BLK_ALL_RECORDS');

  FIRST_RECORD;


    IF :FRM_ALL_ROWS.CHK_SELECT = 1 THEN
      :FRM_REJECTION.ID := :FRM_ALL_ROWS.ID;
        GO_BLOCK('BLK_REJECTION');
        SHOW_VIEW('CNV_REJECTION');
        EXIT;
     ELSE
         NEXT_RECORD;
     END IF;   

END;
```

And the rejection form has two buttons, one to confirm and one to cancel. Let's just focus on the cancel button for now. Here is the code that is executed once the Cancel button is pressed:

```
:BLK_ALL_ROWS.CHK_SELECT := 0;  /* Forces removal of the check mark */
GO_BLOCK('BLK_ALL_RECORDS'); 
HIDE_VIEW('CNV_REJECTION');
```

The only problem is : once the dialog form appears, it hides the parent form, until the form is dismissed. How can display the dialog form ontop of the parent form with both of them visible (in a modal way?)

Comment: there should be an option in Property Palette to set a window as modal

Comment: @Sathya thanks. I forgot to mention that I have already set the MODAL property to YES in the Window pallete, but the parent canvas always disappears when the child is on display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was the problem finally.
The parent Window had a property [`Hide On Exit`] which is defaulted to `Yes` and that made the parent form disappear everytime another window is on display. I set it to `NO` and called the other form. This time both windows are visible, with the modal one always on top.

Answer (score 1):

The navigation between different canvases can be little bit tricky to get to work. Hard to say what is the problem with not having the form in front of me but the first thing I should do is making sure that the 'Raise on entry' canvas property of the 'main' canvas is set to 'Yes'. This should force this canvas to be displayed when you are moving the cursor back to block 'BLK_ALL_RECORDS'.

Another alternative could be to use SHOW_VIEW() in the cancel dialog logic to force the main canvas to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried both of your suggestions, but finally found out that the problem was not with the child window, but the parent. See my answer